# How to extrude as a round shape in concentrated areas?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, extrude, bevel

I hope that I'm explaining my question right as I'm new to blender but I really am at a loss here. I've been stuck for a couple days now of what to do with this.

So, I'm trying to make a side table, this one specifically: [here](https://greatdanecontract.com/tables/coffee-side-tables/petit-palais). Everything was going good until I came to the point where I needed to extract round shapes (sorry, I don't know how to explain this), which I've watched many tutorials and thought I could do it also, but I couldn't. I've added more loop cuts, did the bevel action (which created a totally weird shape in diff directions), etc. Either I'm doing those things wrong (possibly since I'm new) or I just have to re-do what I did to make it so I can do these actions correctly.

Let me show you some photos to help explain what I mean (top is what my whole thing looks like, bottom w/paint done on it to show what I need it look like):

[image]

[image]

So in the first photo I did bevel it because I thought that was what could help me make it round but I could only do the sides of each face to get it round. I have had no idea how to do make the whole thing extend round. I also have no idea how to then make all of them the same size etc so I ran into that as well.

I'm sorry if this makes no sense. I have no idea how to correctly term things but I hope someone could help me or point me in the right direction on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it.

lets say we have our initial shape (mine is slightly different):

[image: initial]

I extrude a rectangle out of each one (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , extrude along normals):

[image: 2]

Now, I select only the long edges (this can be done quickly using the box select in x-ray):

[image: f]

Then, I just bevel the edges to create a circle:

[image: ciflc]

Final Result:

[image: final]

If you want yours to be more circular, just extrude out a larger square initially.

Comment: thanks so much for explaining! I really appreciate your simple steps. I did manage to get the shape so I'm happy with the result. I now have a problem where there is a weird opening on the top and bottoms? I have no idea what I did to get it like that. I may have pressed something without realizing it? But some of my mesh is like broken up, if that makes sense? Here are some photos: https://i.imgur.com/IegSuqB.png + https://i.imgur.com/QvMKcoG.png

Comment: actually nevermind! I managed to figure it out. Your explanation helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One way of accomplishing the effect you desire is with the proportional editing tool.

I've started out with geometry fairly similar to yours.

[image]

Select one of the edges along the top or bottom of one of the slats and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> > Length to select all of the edges of the same length.

Subdivide these edges, and click the number of cuts up to 3.

Turn your proportional editing tool on, and set the mode to Sphere.

[image]

Somewhat tediously, select only the center edge of the new edges created by subdividing.

[image]

Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the scaling to the X-Y plane. Move your mouse to control the amount of scaling, and use the scroll wheel to control the size of the proportional effect as represented by the white circle. When you get it right, click to confirm.

[image]

An alternative to save some time would be to delete all but one slat, perform these same operations on just that one slat, and then duplicate and rotate that slat around the circle.

Comment: nice, this method seems much cleaner than mine.

Comment: Maybe @person132 but your is simpler, which is also useful for beginners.

Comment: they should really implement a Select Similar > symmetric about axis option for things like this

Comment: @Rekov thank you so much! I did what you explained and I got the shapes I needed. I feel a huge relief. After I did that I noticed that some of the tops and bottoms of the shapes were missing? Did I do something wrong? Here's some photos: https://i.imgur.com/IegSuqB.png + https://i.imgur.com/QvMKcoG.png

Comment: @Rekov y'know what I actually figured it out so thanks for your help!